# Change line color to a gradient in an animation in Python

Tags: python, animation

I crafted the following piece of code, which draws a planet circling around the sun:

(solorbita[0] has the x points of the orbit of the planet, solorbita[1] has the y points)

I drawed some part of the orbit behind the planet so that it looks like the trail of a shooting star. I would like that trail to be orange-ish far from the planet and red close to it.
Any help is appreciated.

```
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
from matplotlib.animation import PillowWriter
from IPython.display import HTML
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle, Arrow
#Creamos la figura
fig = plt.figure() 
ax = plt.axes()
ax.set_xlim(min(solorbita[0]) - 0.25, max(solorbita[0]) + 0.25)
ax.set_ylim(min(solorbita[2]) - 0.25, max(solorbita[2]) + 0.25)

trajectory, = ax.plot([], [])
punto, =ax.plot([1],[0],'o', markersize=12, color="orange")
punto2=ax.plot([0],[0],'o',markersize=18, color="red")

def animate(i):
    
    punto.set_data([solorbita[0][i]],[solorbita[2][i]])
    # Actualizamos la trayectoria 
    if i<10:
      trajectory.set_data([solorbita[0][j] for j in range(i)], [solorbita[2][j] for j in range(i)])

    if i>=10:
      trajectory.set_data([solorbita[0][j] for j in range(i-10,i)], [solorbita[2][j] for j in range(i-10,i)])
    return trajectory, 

#Creamos la animación
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=10, blit=False, save_count=700)
plt.show()   
os.makedirs('./animations', exist_ok=True)

FFwriter = animation.FFMpegWriter(fps=30)
anim.save('./animations/orbita.gif', writer=FFwriter)
```

Comment: `solorbita` is not defined....  where does this come from please ?

Comment: its the result from applying runge kutta 4 method to a diff equation

Comment: the current code requires this result (presumably a list) prior to it being used in the plot...   so just after the imports.